# Efficient pandas between() for any of multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame looking like this

```
data = [["2020-01-01", "2020-01-01"], ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-04"], ["2020-01-05", "2020-01-06"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["START", "END"]).astype({"END": "datetime64[ns]" , "START": "datetime64[ns]"})
```

|  | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-04 |
| 2 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-06 |

and

a Series/numpy array of `datetime64[ns]` like this

`timestamps = pd.Series(["2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"], dtype="datetime64[ns]")`

For every row of `df` I want to know if there is at least one value in `timestamps` which lies inbetween `START` and `END`.

<s>I can do the following</s>

```
df["START"].apply(lambda x: (timestamps >= x).any()) & df["END"].apply(lambda x: (timestamps <= x).any())
```

resulting in `[False, True, False]`, but is there a more performant or built-in way without using `df.apply`?

**EDIT**:
Actually, my solution using `apply` was incorrect because if we had

`timestamps = pd.Series(["2019-01-01", "2021-01-01"], dtype="datetime64[ns]")`

the output would be `[True, True, True]`, which is obviously false. However, the accepted answer does produce a correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can broadcast the values in `START` and `END` columns to create a boolean mask, then reduce the resulting boolean mask along `axis=1`

```
t = timestamps.values
((df['START'].values[:, None] <= t) & (df['END'].values[:, None] >= t)).any(1)
```

---

```
array([False,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`IntervalIndex.overlaps`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.overlaps.html) if possible create `Interval` from `timestamps` by minimal and maximal values:

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['START'], 
                                 df['END'], 
                                 closed='both')

i = pd.Interval(timestamps.min(), timestamps.max(), closed='both')
out = s.overlaps(i)
print (out )
[False  True False]
```

Comment: This is not really what I need. I don't want to convert the timestamps to an interval, but for every interval in s check if it contains at least one timestamp from timestamps.